# hateoas links are not properly creating after spring boot 3 upgrade

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-17, spring-hateoas, spring-boot-3

After upgrading to springboot 3 and java 17 from 1.8 I am facing an issue with spring hateoas link been created by the *WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo*
The expected link was

```
https://test.com/dutyofcare/v1/bookings/8fcc2cc9-fc63-4bb4-acdf-2f3a11efd9f1
enter code here
```

but the actual link created after upgrade was below,

```
https://api.beta.eks.us-west-2.lab.egencia.cloud/doc-service/v1/bookings/8fcc2cc9-fc63-4bb4-acdf-2f3a11efd9f1
```

some how dutyofcare is been overriden by doc-service and the response for this get endpoint was 404 not found (even when i manually change it to dutyofcare also it is throwing error 404)

I have recently updated the hateos dependency to this for the upgrade.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Please see the assembler created for building links

```html
import DutyOfCareDataRetrieveController;
import DutyOfCareDataResponseBean;
import MetadataBean;
import ErrorCode;
import DutyOfCareTechnicalException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.hateoas.Link;
import org.springframework.hateoas.EntityModel;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import static ErrorCode.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo;
import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.methodOn;

@Component
public class DocDataResourceAssembler extends SimpleResourceAssembler<DutyOfCareDataResponseBean> {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DocDataResourceAssembler.class);

    @Override
    protected void addLinks(EntityModel<DutyOfCareDataResponseBean> resource) {
        try {
            DutyOfCareDataResponseBean dutyOfCareDataResponseBean = resource.getContent();
            MetadataBean metadata = dutyOfCareDataResponseBean.getMetadata();
            final String resourceId = dutyOfCareDataResponseBean.getResourceId();
            int currentPage = metadata.getCurrentPage();
            int totalPages = metadata.getTotalPages();
            if ((currentPage < totalPages)) {
                String url = linkTo(methodOn(DutyOfCareDataRetrieveController.class).
                        getBookings(resourceId, currentPage)).withRel("next").getHref().split("\\?")[0];
                Link link = Link.of(url).withRel("next");
                LOGGER.info("Generated URL for testing: " + url); // Add this line to log the generated URL
                resource.add(link);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception occurred while adding Hateoas links.");
            throw new DutyOfCareTechnicalException(ErrorCode.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Can some one help me to figure out?